# Lightningcharts - Resetting axis on double clicking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zooming, double-click, lightningchart

I am facing the following problem. When I want to set the minimum boundaries up to which the user can zoom in the chart, double click on the axis stops working. Here is a piece of code to help you understand.
Function HandleScaleChangeY needed to simultaneously scroll multiple charts. What am I doing wrong?

```
 const HandleScaleChangeY = (yAxisIndex) => {
            return (start, end) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) {
                    let newStart, newEnd

                    if (start < end) {
                        newStart = end
                        newEnd = start
                    } else {
                        newStart = start
                        newEnd = end
                    }
                    const axis = yAxes[i]

                    if (i !== yAxisIndex && (axis.scale.getInnerStart() !== newStart || axis.scale.getInnerEnd() !== newEnd))
                        if (newStart-newEnd<10000) {
                            axis.setInterval(axis.scale.getInnerStart(), axis.scale.getInnerEnd())
                        } else{
                            axis.setScrollStrategy(undefined)
                                .setInterval(newStart, newEnd)
                        }
                }
            }
        }

for (let i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) {
    const yAxis = yAxes[i]
    yAxis.onScaleChange(HandleScaleChangeY(i))
}
```

The problem is that after the condition `if (newStart-newEnd<10000)` is triggered, double clicking on the axis stops working (the axis range does not return to the initial state)

Comment: Hi, could you please edit the answer to elaborate more, which is your issue:
a) user can zoom too far into chart.
b) double click on axis is not working (what would you expect this to do?).
c) Y axes of multiple charts should simultaneously scroll (please elaborate on how you'd like this to behave, also).

Comment: Hi, double click does not work after the condition is met if (newStart-newEnd<10000). Usually the axis interval is reset after double clicking on the axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-clicking on a LCJS Axis "releases" the axis, letting it scroll automatically if it was previously frozen.

However, an Axis can only scroll automatically if it has an active `ScrollStrategy`.

I see in your code that you are using `axis.setScrollStrategy(undefined)`, this will disable all automatic scrolling on the axis, unless re-enabled by setting: `axis.setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)`, or some other scroll strategy other than `undefined`.

If you want to set Axis interval, and temporarily freeze it (until user double click), you can do this: `Axis.setInterval(newStart, newEnd, false, true)`

..where the first boolean `false` controls whether the transition is animated,
and the second boolean `true` controls whether to freeze the axis afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using Axis.setInterval(newStart, newEnd, false, true) instead of 
 axis.setScrollStrategy(undefined).setInterval(newStart, newEnd) solved the problem